# Hash Join Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have two tables, each one stored in a List.
The table has two columns (thus arrays in lists are of size two)

```
List<int[]> tablea;
List<int[]> tableb;
```

Content of tablea

```
 a b 
{1,2}
{3,4}
{5,6}
```

content of tableb

```
 b c
{2,3}
{2,4}
{6,7}
```

Now I wish to join two tables by field b, hence the result is

```
 a b c
{1,2,3}
{1,2,4}
{5,6,7}
```

I know I can do this is sort merge join algorithms, and the algorithms is quite intuitive.
But I heard hybrid hashjoin(mentioned here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join#_note-1) is faster.

May I know how to use hybrid hashjoin algorithms to join tablea and tableb in C#(Preferably) or java?
(What I concern here is speed rather than space)

Comment: Are the values of column `b` bounded? In that case, you can just use an array with the direct values, rather than calculating a hash for each (which will be even faster).

Comment: Why would you want to count a hash table for ints collection? It's pointless IMO. I don't know about the algorhitm but I highly doubt CLR wouldn't use most effective way of joining for general purpose already.

Comment: Your question seems odd because you are attempting to join two collections of just ints, and you're implying that the smaller of the two is so huge that it won't fit in memory. This is an unusual situation for a beginning programmer, and in addition you indicate that you can implement the solution in multiple languages (is this a homework problem?), but can't understand the fairly clear Wikipedia page laying out the hybrid hash join algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ode that can handle non-unique key values, would be like this:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int[]>> hashA = new Dictionary<int, List<int[]>>();
    foreach (int[] a in tablea) {
       List<int> list;
       if (!hashA.TryGetValue(a[1], out list) {
          list = new List<int>();
          hashA.Add(a[1], list);
       }
       list.Add(a);
    }
    List<int[]> result = new List<int[]>();
    foreach (int[] b in tableb) {
       List<int[]> a;
       if (hashA.TryGetValue(b[0], out a) {
          foreach (int[] line in a) {
             result.Add(new int[] { line[0], line[1], b[1] });
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I down-voted your answer because the OP asked about the hybrid hash join algorithm.